# What's the phrase for food burning and sticking to the pan?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When cooking neglectfully, food sometimes burns and sticks to the pan (or pot, or whatever one is cooking in). What is this phenomenon called in English?

> Darn it! The spaghetti `<stuck to the pot>`!

Is there an idiomatic expression?

Comment: I'm afraid not, considering how often it happens!  The best you could do I believe is say exactly what you mean - it stuck or burnt to the pan.

Comment: It's not an exact match, but if someone shouted, "Darn it, I scorched the spaghetti," I would imagine that the pasta's surface had been darkened by contact with the cooking pot, and I wouldn't be at all surprised to learn that the pasta had stuck to the pot as well.

Comment: @Sven Yargs Pasta sticking to the pot tends to more often be dried-out pasta rather than burnt pasta, though that might be the problem - we're trying to think of a single word that describes two distinct phenomena.

Comment: I've used "burnt to the pot" before to indicate that I've both burnt and stuck food to the pot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the nearest to a single-word expression is ***burnt on***.

> The spaghetti boiled dry and now it's burnt on.

---

> [Thriftyfun](http://www.thriftyfun.com/Cleaning-Burnt-Pots-and-Pans-Guide.html)
>
> Occasionally it happens that foods are burned onto your cookware, and it can be a challenge to get it clean again. This is a guide about cleaning burnt pots and pans.

Answer (score 1):

The most common expression is what you used in your question:

> Arg, my brownies stuck to the pan.

If you explicitly need to mention a burnt status then you would simply combine the expression:

> Arg, my brownies burnt and stuck to the pan.