# Is there an English word that means literally 'of the same material'?

Tags: single-word-requests

and also has homo- or con- in it? It also needs to be a general word that can be used in, for example, a fiction literary story that has nothing to do with science: an imaginary thing, a word somehow like *homogeneous* or *homologous*. I need to say that something is “of the same material” as something else. If I had the word and could fill in the blank, my sentence should be:

> X is ***_*__*_*_** to Y

meaning X is made of the exact same material as Y.

Comment: You might try two words: *materially identical*.  X is materially identical to Y.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a word 'homomaterial' I am not entirely clear about its meaning, but it may be of help. You can find more by clicking on [**this link**](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DtLTTAYvBFkC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=homomaterial&source=bl&ots=k1ex9P5kgQ&sig=nZn8KRNNc1z-1VwbCsP0nzAFCg4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lDt2UuKPIcWy0AXe6IG4Cg&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=homomaterial&f=false).

Comment: Thanks! can I say this for example: Homo-material to ash?

Comment: @Hamed I'm not sure what that means. And the word homomaterial which I saw was not hyphenated.

Comment: stack exchange spellchecker suggested it hyphenated. about the meaning, to clarify I name another example. you see it is correct if I say 'similar to ash'. But I don't need to word similar because it doesn't imply the material it is made of.

Comment: @Harned - You can't trust spellcheckers when you're dealing with rare or specialized words. The suggested word provided here clearly has precedent, but, if you decide to use it, I woudn't expect your readers to recoginize it. You'd probably be better off using "X is made of the same material as Y," or, "X and Y are both made of..."

Comment: What is the reason for this? you mean English speakers can not accept that something is of the same material as something else? even when it is fiction? or is it because of the lack of words? I don't understand why it is impossible to use such word for these occasions.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a common word that means what you are looking for a word to mean. Sometimes that happens in English. Insofar as I know, there's no single word for _"my girlfriend's brother, who also happens to be my best friend";_ or _"running from the police, even though a person has done nothing wrong";_ or [_"food that is burnt and has stuck to the pan"_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133884). We do have the idiom _cut from the same cloth_, but that's used more to describe the character or nature of two people, more so that the physical material something is made from.

Comment: @Hamed I don't think that you could say "homo-material to ash" because you would have to be describing something that was _made_ from the _same material as_ ash. You can make things out of some kinds of ash (building blocks and roads for example) but the ash is then a material. You might be able to say "the jacket was homo-material to the trousers" or "the garage was homo-material to the house" to say that the jacket and trousers matched or that both buildings were constructed from identical bricks (or ash blocks) but not many English speakers would know what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

> **homogenous** *adjective* 1:  of the same or a similar kind or nature

if you want something that is consistent.  Howver, if you want to emphasize *exactly* the same you might prefer

> **isogenic** *adjective*:  characterized by essentially identical genes

*from m-w.com*

Answer (score 0):

There is [homoousion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoousion), a beautiful word with a long theological history in Christianity. It means "one in being" or "of single essence". It was contrasted with [homoiousianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiousian) (from ὅμοιος, hómoios, "similar", as opposed to ὁμός, homós, "same") and [heteroousianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteroousianism) (meaning "different" in substance).